# Enumerate printing extra line when iterating

Tags: python

This is a method that I am writing for a class, for some reason this returns an ONE extra line than intended. The code below is just a testing, the values are not representative.

```
n = ""

dixoncider = ["a","f","f","g","f"]

for count,ele in enumerate(dixoncider,0):
    if count is len(dixoncider):
        break
    else:
        n = n + str(count) + ": " + str(ele) + "\n"
print(n)
```

Output which is wrong:

```
0: a
1: f
2: f
3: g
4: f
```

Comment: Extraneous conditional: `if count is len(dixoncider):`. But, if it was needed use `==`, as in `if count == len(dixoncider):`.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the empty line at the end, that's because you are appending a linebreak (`\n`) after each value, so the last character of your output is going to be that linebreak.

If you could see that character, you have this:

```
0: a\n
1: f\n
2: f\n
3: g\n
4: f\n
‍
```

And want this:

```
0: a\n
1: f\n
2: f\n
3: g\n
4: f   <- No linebreak here.
```

If you want to get rid of that, you can replace the `print(n)` with `print(n[:-1])` to skip that last character.

Alternatively, just add the `\n` conditionally within the loop in all but the last iteration.